# SQL Server - Update So many Records at a time with a Replace Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have have some queries that run an update with a replace function. For Example:

```
Update my_table set mycolumn=replace(my_column,@OldServer,@NewServer)
```

What I am trying to accomplish is trying to update so many rows at a time. Let's just say I want to do two rows at a time. Here is what I have tried

```
use mydb
DECLARE @OldServer1 varchar(255)

DECLARE @OldServer2 varchar(255)

DECLARE @NewServer1 varchar(255)

DECLARE @NewServer1 varchar(255)



--Edit these values

SET @OldServer = 'abc'

SET @NewServer = 'ghi'

print 'My Table'

set rowcount 2

update my_table
set my_column=replace(my_column, @OldServer, @NewServer)

while @@rowcount>0

Begin

Set Rowcount 2
update my_table
set my_column=replace(my_column, @OldServer, @NewServer)

END
Set Rowcount 0
```

What happens is that the table is only updated by two rows and it loops over and over. I'm guessing the replace assumes everything. I also tried a top count and it done the same thing. Any ideas on how I can accomplish my goal?

Comment: add `WHERE my_column <> @NewServer` in the second `update`

Comment: @Lamak Using replace, so I assume that there's more text than that... `NOT LIKE`  would be better

Comment: @JohnHC yeah, you're right, but it was just the idea of adding a condition to the `update` to filter the rows that already were updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no natural row number in an SQL table, so you will need to make one

declare @StartNo INT;
declare @EndNo INT;
declare @LastNo INT;

```
set @StartNo = 1;
set @EndNo = 2;
set @LastNo = (select count(*) from My_Table);

while @StartNo <= @LastNo
begin
with CTE as
  (
    select M1.*, row_number() over (order by OrderColumn) as Row_Ord
    from My_Table
  )
update CTE
set My_Column = replace(my_column, @OldServer, @NewServer)
where Row_Ord between @StartNo and @EndNo;

set @StartNo = @EndNo + 2;
set @EndNo = @EndNo + 2;

end
```